# Puppet to start service if it exists on windows

Tags: puppet

I am looking for a manifest to start a service on windows server if the service exists. 
I am looking to check a service with a condition if the file exists.

```
service { 'test service':
   ensure => 'running',
   enable => true,
   unless  => 'if((test-path "C:\Program Files\test1") -or (test-path "C:/Program Files/test2")){ exit 0 } else { exit 1 }',
   provider => powershell,}
```

Above code returns an error that unless is an invalid parameter. Any other way to check? 
Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it doesn't look like the service resource has a parameter to support conditional inclusion. Puppet also does not have an easy way to check for the existence of a file on the client that I'm aware of. I have gotten around this by creating a custom fact that checked the condition I needed and then wrapping the resource in an unless block:

```
unless $facts['test_file_exists'] {
  service { 'test service':
    ensure => 'running',
    enable => true,
  }
```

since a custom fact can be written in any language that can output "key=value" pairs to stdout you could use your existing powershell code as a fact with a small change:

```
if((test-path "C:\Program Files\test1") -or (test-path "C:\program Files\test2")){
      write-host "test_file_exists=true
}
else{
    write-host "test_file_exists=false"
}
```

there are a few different ways to distribute the fact out to your client systems. I prefer to put the fact into a module and let pluginsync distribute it out for me. If you don't want to include it in a module then you would have to find some way to get the powershell code into C:\ProgramData\PuppetLabs\facter\facts.d\ with the proper .ps1 extension on the end.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Could you please let me know on where should we place the custum facts in module? /etc/puppet/test-module/facts.d in puppet master? Can we place power shell scripts or ruby is required?

Comment: No problem it would go in: <MODULEPATH>/<MODULE>/facts.d/ I should mention also that you need to have at least puppet 3.4 for this to work